# BTRFS - Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, filesystems, btrfs

I know this may be a silly question. I want to install Arch Linux on my computer. And umm..., this time I would like to use btrfs. Would I need to create a `/boot/efi` partition and a `/boot` partition just like in Fedora?
I mean, do something like this:

```
nvme0n1                                   2XX:0    0     1.9T       0 disk  
├─nvme0n1p1                               2XX:1    0     550M       0 part  /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2                               2XX:2    0     600M       0 part  /boot
└─nvme0n1p3                               2XX:3    0     287.6G     0 part  
  └─luks-...
                                          2XX:0    0 287.6G  0 crypt /home
                                                                     /
```

or `/boot` would be enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The EFI partition must have the type (filesystem) FAT32, If you are going to use btrfs everywhere, an exception must be made for the EFI, hence you need a separate partition.

A separate /boot partition is optional. It can make the sysadmin's life easier in some setups with LVM, raid, LUKS. If not sure, make a 500MB /boot partition.

Comment: Thank you, VPfB.